# reduce memory dedicated to pandas dtype=object

Tags: python, pandas, object, memory

Is it possible to set a custom length for object data type in Python pandas?
For example, in my test data frame, one column with dtyp=object increases it's size ~60%. Though the values in this column are just "Y" or "N".

*"Passing memory_usage='deep' will enable a more accurate memory usage report, that accounts for the full usage of the contained objects"*

```
df.info(memory_usage='deep')
```

dtypes: datetime64ns, float64(8), int16(2), int8(4), object(1)
**memory usage: 14.7 MB**

```
df.info()
```

dtypes: datetime64ns, float64(8), int16(2), int8(4), object(1)
**memory usage: 9.2+ MB**

This looks like very memory inefficient, though I couldn't find any option/data type, which could reduce the size. (for example, like int8 instead of int64)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Best way to deal with that is to use [Categoricals](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html). It will use `int8` to store the values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.choice(['Y', 'N'], size=10**6)})
df.info(memory_usage='deep')
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1000000 entries, 0 to 999999
Data columns (total 1 columns):
A    1000000 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 62.9 MB
```

---

```
df['A'] = df['A'].astype('category')
```

---

```
df.info(memory_usage='deep')
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1000000 entries, 0 to 999999
Data columns (total 1 columns):
A    1000000 non-null category
dtypes: category(1)
memory usage: 976.8 KB
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved everything. Just had some confusion that 'category' is not supported in read_csv, but it was due to my bad syntax.

Comment: @GrinvydasKareiva You are welcome. For read_csv, the support for categoricals started in version 0.19 I think. Also make sure you have the latest version.